# Detect Flaming in Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am searching for a algorithm that counts multiple sequential characters and counts all words written in caps.

The output I want to have is that for every word written in caps a counter is increased by 1 and for every sequentially used character the counter is again increased by 1

Example:

str = "COME ON DUDE!!!"

counter = 4

Explaination: COME +1, ON +1, DUDE +1, !!! +1

Any ideas on how to achieve this specific algorithm?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is your friend.

```
import re

test = "COME ON DUDE!!!"
count = len(re.findall('([A-Z]{2,})|(?P<r>\S)(?P=r){2,}', test))
```

Of course, you should look at the `.findall()` output with some more test strings to make sure it's actually counting what you want it to. (That's why I included an extra capture group.)